# Как передать содержимое input в слайдер jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Как сделать чтобы ползунок самостоятельно передвинулся на отметку которую ввёл в input?

```
    <input id="hidden" step="1" min="55" max="170" name="y" type="text" size="3" value="100">
    <div class="slider">
        <span class="ui-slider-handle">
            <div id="slider-result">100</div>    
        </span>
    </div>
```

js

```
$(".slider").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    animate: true,
    range: false,
    value: 100,
    min: 55,
    max: 170,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
        $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);
    }
});
```

Пример [codepen](http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/zvmeQq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [метод value](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value):

> value( value ) Set the value of the slider. Code examples:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "value", 55 );
```

Вам нужно проделать то же самое, только вот так:

```
$('#hidden').on('keyup', function(){
   $( ".selector" ).slider( "value", this.value );
}).trigger('change'); //это чтобы ползунок установлися в нужную позицию, как только отрендерится страница
```

Comment: После первой попытки перестаёт вообще работать. Куда это вставить? `"value", this.value `

Comment: Это все нужно завернуть в domReady, иначе ни Ваш код, ни мой не имеют смысла

Comment: Я ставил и отдельно, перестаёт потом работать слайдер

Comment: Не получается у меня. input почти работает, так слайдер перестаёт работать. Что к меня не так?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdGEEg - см. для первого слайдера, для остальных аналогично. Обратите внимание - код завернут в domReady. И да, эффективнее оказалось применить keyup, а не change, как я писал ранее.

Comment: Так тоже слайдером потом не регулируется.

Comment: Один раз ввёл в input, слайдер передвинулся, а после слайдером уже не отрегулировать.

Comment: Обновите мой пример. Проблема в этом: $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value); не надо обращаться к value как к атрибуту, используйте val()

Comment: Спасибо! Всё отлично.